# Как получить несколько значений из связанной таблицы в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблицы:

```
$table1 - book с полями book_id, name, price, description;
$table2 - author с полями author_id, author;
$table3 - genre с полями genre_id, genre;
$table4 - book_author с полями id, book_id, author_id;
$table5 - book_genre с полями id, book_id, genre_id;
```

Каждая книга может иметь несколько авторов и жанров в связанных таблицах (book_author и book_genre).

Формирую запрос на выборку всех данных из таблиц:

```
$find = mysqli_query($this->db, "SELECT * 
                                 FROM $table1  
                                 JOIN $table4 ON $table1.book_id = $table4.book_id  
                                 JOIN $table2 ON $table4.author_id = $table2.author_id  
                                 JOIN $table5 ON $table1.book_id = $table5.book_id  
                                 JOIN $table3 ON $table5.genre_id = $table3.genre_id");
```

И вывожу его в цикле:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($find)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Программа выводит массивы сначала с одним автором и разными жанрами, затем с другим автором и те ми же жанрами (при чём в одном массиве один автор - один жанр, то есть сколько авторов и жанров, столько и массивов с разными сочетаниями этих запросов всего лишь для одной книги).

Как это можно исправить, чтобы одним запросом и массивом вывести корректно данные на экран со всеми авторами и жанрами для этой книги?

Comment: Попробуйте так `"SELECT * FROM $table1 LEFT JOIN $table4 ON $table1.book_id = $table4.book_id LEFT JOIN $table2 ON $table4.author_id = $table2.author_id LEFT JOIN $table5 ON $table1.book_id = $table5.book_id LEFT JOIN $table3 ON $table5.genre_id = $table3.genre_id"`,

Comment: Запрос возвращает строго прямоугольную таблицу, у нее только 2 измерения, строки и столбцы. А вы сейчас хотите видимо что то четырехмерное. Сначала приведите пример, как должен выглядеть в двумерном виде вывод запроса.

Comment: *вывести корректно данные* Что значит "корректно"? сейчас - тоже корректно. Только, как я понимаю, вид не устраивает... попробуйте начать с замены звезды на список реально нужных полей и указать требуемую сортировку результата.

Comment: LEFT или какой-либо другой JOIN ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Вот пример как выводятся 1 книга:                                                                                                                                  array
  'book_id' => '1'
  'name' => 'Gremuirium Imperium'
  'author' => 'alerzi al hazradji'
  'genre' => 'magia'
  'price' => '1'
  'description' => 'qwerty'
array
  'book_id' => '1'
  'name' => 'Gremuirium Imperium'
  'author' => 'sergey kamenev'
  'genre' => 'magia'
  'price' => '1'
  'description' => 'qwerty'
А мне нужно чтобы вся информация об одной книге была в одном массиве с двумя авторами и жанрами.

Answer (score 0):

Удобнее всего выводить не одним запросом, а тремя
Сначала получить все книги, потом собрать все их id и затем сделать два запроса к жанрам и авторам через book_id IN (...);

Сответственно, забыть про mysqli как про страшный сон, и делать что-то вроде

```
$books = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM books")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE)
$ids = array_keys($books);
```

и дальше два запроса, к жанрам и авторам, IN формируем [как показано здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)